# React SPFx advanced Search box and results in Modern pages

Tags: search, search-box, search-results-webpart

I have found a few examples of search web parts in [Github](https://github.com/estruyf/Search-WP-SPFx) and they are good as starting point, but I was wondering if there are any examples of advanced search?

Answer (score 1):

Hi following is the most complete search web part for modern pages I know of created by Franck Cornu & Mikael Svenson:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ModernSearch/react-search-refiners

Comment: Hi Jems, adding details about the solution would be great contribution. Links may not work in future :)